# Getting files names with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

I am trying to get all the Files names from a directory "blabla"

and only from that directory without its sub-directorys

and i need all those names without the X first names and Y last names

and without its path (only the file names themselfs

i tried

```
#!/bin/bash
find blavla | sort
```

but it gave me all the files including the subfolders files

and it gave me FULL name (with the path)

and i have no idea how to reed without the X first and Y last names

tried to search online and reading the man find but didnt find nothing

Comment: Use a glob: `files=( * )`. Or to print them: `printf '%s\n' *`.

Comment: can you please explain this for a bit?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Comment: do you mean you want to use find as a ls blabla ?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) alert! what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} ';' | \
sort | \
awk 'BEGIN { X = 2; Y = 2 } { lines[NR] = $0 } END { for (i=1 + X; i<=NR - Y; i++) print lines[i] }'
```

Set X and Y to how many file names you want to skip at the beginning and at the end of the list respectively.

Comment: exelent, but i still get the full path of the files and how i cont read the first X and last Y files?

Comment: @JohnnyF: I've updated the command to only print the base names without the paths. Do you want the first X and the last Y files alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (substitute Y and X with actual values):

```
cd blavla && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f|head -n -Y|tail -n +(X+1)
```